# How to enable specific signature algorithms in Java SSL

Tags: java, security, ssl, rsa, java-security

I would like to enable only two signature algorithms in Java: `SHA512 WITH RSA` and `SHA256 WITH RSA`) on SSL handshake.

I tried to edit the `java.security` file but without success 
(edited field: `jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms`). Also, I tried to set up `SSLParameters` class but there isn't any field to pass for the sign-algorithm.

Comment: Yes there is: it is done via [`SSLParameters.setAlgorithmConstraints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html#setAlgorithmConstraints-java.security.AlgorithmConstraints-).

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for help. Could you help me how to transfer all algorithms for cipher but leave only SHA256 for signature?

Comment: You need to figure it ot yourself from the Javadoc. Cut and paste isn't the road to success.